# How is set closed under multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra

$S=\lbrace f(x)=a_n x^n + . . . a_1x+a_0\in\mathbb{R}_n[x]∣a_i=0$ if i is even$\rbrace$.

What I tried: Let $a,b\in S$. When I try to multiply a by b in the conventional way we multiply polynomials, the resulting expression does not satisfy the "if i is even, $r\in S$, $r_i=0$" statement. I know that S is supposed to be closed under multiplication. What am I missing?

Comment: This is definitely false. Try multiplying $f(x)=x$ by itself. Is it perhaps meant to be $a_i=0$ if $i$ is *odd*?

Comment: I’m completely sure that I just saw the exact same question a few minutes ago (already with an answer underneath it and some edits to the question). Did you delete your question and then reposted it?

Comment: Since it's tagged [tag:linear-algebra], it's probably supposed to be closed under **scalar** multiplication, if I had to guess.

Comment: @Jendrik I answered then deleted my answer because it was based on a guess that psj36 seems to agree with and I realized there was notation I didn't understand. This could be the same question; I can't see deleted answers on the Android app.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. It must be closed under scalar multiplication. I totally missed that.